# R per ID column remove rows by list of values

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I have a dataframe with multiple rows per ID column but I only want to keep one row. Unfortunately I cannot use my real dataframe so I'll create a similar hypothetical dataframe below.

```
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| ID | name   | org                |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 1  | Apple  | Apple              |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 1  | Apple  | Sour               |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 1  | Apple  | Goldstar           |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 2  | Banana | Banana             |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 2  | Banana | banana             |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 3  | Yogi   | yogi               |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 3  | yogi   | strawberry yoghurt |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
```

I am looking for a way to remove all rows except for the first one it finds in a list of possible values, if there is no match then keep all.

in this hypothetical situation I want to give the function a list of values such as:

```
appleNamesTokeep <- c("Goldstar", "Apple", "Sour")
bananaNamesTokeep <- c("Banana", "banana") #Capital sensitive
yoghurtNamesTokeep <- c("strawberry yoghurt", "yogi")
```

And the result would be

```
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| ID | name   | org                |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 1  | Apple  | Goldstar           |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 2  | Banana | Banana             |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
| 3  | yogi   | strawberry yoghurt |  |
+----+--------+--------------------+--+
```

If it finds a row with the name column value "Goldstar" it should remove all others, if it doesnt find a goldstar but it does have an "Apple" it should keep that one instead and remove everything else instead, and so on. It should look per ID and for each list, since every row could be about a totally different topic (different type of food in this case).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with base R:

```
i1 <- match(tolower(substr(mydf$name,1,3)), substr(NamesTokeep$ind,1,3))
i2 <- match(mydf$org, NamesTokeep$values)
```

Now Using:

```
mydf[which(i1 & i2),]
```

gives you:

> ```
>   ID   name                org
> 3  1  Apple           Goldstar
> 4  2 Banana             Banana
> 7  3   yogi strawberry yoghurt
> ```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
                       name = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Yogi", "yogi"),
                       org = c("Apple", "Sour", "Goldstar", "Banana", "banana", "yogi", "strawberry yoghurt")),
                  .Names = c("ID", "name", "org"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

NamesTokeep <- stack(list(apple = c("Goldstar", "Apple", "Sour"),
                          banana = c("Banana", "banana"),
                          yoghurt = c("strawberry yoghurt", "yogi")))[2:1]
NamesTokeep <- aggregate(values ~ ind, data = NamesTokeep, '[', 1)
```